# Sorting Python lists of objects by keys with different names

Tags: python, django, sorting

I used to merge and sort 2 lists of objects that both have a "created" attributes which is a datetime.

I dit it this way and this worked well:

```
all_events = sorted(
    chain(list1, list2),
        key=attrgetter('created'))
```

Now, I'd like to add a 3rd list in the sort. The problem is the datetime attribute of objects in that 3rd list is not named 'created'.

How would you do to sort the 3 lists in that case?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a job for the old-school way, [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `lambda` to get the attribute with fallback:

```
all_events = sorted(
    chain(list1, list2, list3),
    key=lambda o: getattr(o, 'created', getattr(o, 'otherattribute', None))
```

This will try to get either attribute, preferring `'created'`.

Comment: Waoh, that works well, thanks. Not sure to understand how though. I guess I should take a look to `lambda`in the doc :)

Comment: I have a slight worry that if in some future update, the objects from the third list grow a `created` attribute with a different format, this might silently start doing wrong things.

Comment: @user2357112: that's always a risk with mixing heterogeneous objects and changing code.

Comment: @DavidW.: `lambda`s are just one-expression functions; the one expression result is the function return value.